# Big data image processing in Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, tar

I have a 7GB .tgz file that is an archive of thousands of high-res photos I'd like to work with in Python. I am able to do all of the following in the case of a single image, but I'm not sure how to work with such large data and the .tgz file format. I have Googled, but perhaps I'm not using the best search terms. Explicit code will be the most helpful for me to understand.

How do I load this .tgz data into Python? (pickle, numpy, tarfile? pip install tarfile fails.) I will eventually want to convert them to numpy arrays.

How do I make all of the images into a set resolution?

How do I convert all of the images to greyscale?

The goal is to manipulate the data for use in a convolutional neural network (CNN).

Comment: although, not exactly an answer and more of a suggestion: if  you will need to process the data, maybe it's worth un-packing the data first once, then process unpacked images multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if handling the archive is your problem. It's quite obvious that a .tgz file should be handled using `tarfile`. `tarfile` in an inbuilt module in python and you do not need to `pip install` it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# import the tarfile
from tarfile import TarFile

# Open your tarfile for reading
itgz = TarFile.gzopen( "photos.tgz", 'r' )

# Open your tarfile for saving the images
otgz = TarFile.gzopen( "photos_edited.tgz", 'w' )

# Handle the images one-by-one
for img_name in itgz.getnames() :
    # Extract it to where ever you want
    itgz.extract( img_name )

    # Do the image processing numpy, PIL or any tool of your choice

    # If you want to save the edited images back to a tar file
    otgz.add( img_name )

else:
    itgz.close()
    otgz.close()
```

Comment: Instead of `itgz.extract` if you use `itgz.extractfile` you'll get a file like object. The file-like object is read-only and provides the following methods: read(), readline(), readlines(), seek() and tell()

Answer (score 0):

I would use [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) standard module (you don't have to install it - it's already there) for accessing your compress data and [scipy.ndimage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage) for processing your images.

You can start [here](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/)